# grunt-casperjs does not keep grunt-contrib-connect server alive on Windows

Tags: gruntjs, casperjs

I use grunt-casperjs for e2e testing and deploy our code on a test server using grunt-contrib-connect for that. While this works fine on MacOS X, the casperjs tests always fail when running on Windows. The  casperjs task ends before the tests have actually executed. Therefore the connect server shut down again too early. Current Workaround is to start a timer task after the casperjs task to keep the server alive for n seconds for the tests to run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I recently encountered this problem and found a solution.

I was able to fix this by using the [Grunt Event](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#grunt-events) from grunt-contrib-connect.

```
 grunt.registerTask('casper-test', 'casperjs');

 grunt.registerTask('local-test', 'Start Server for Local Test', function() {

    grunt.task.run('casper-test');

    grunt.task.run('connect:server:keepalive');

 });
```